# Integral models of $p$-divisible groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $G$ be a $p$-divisible group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Suppose that $G_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ has a model over $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$.

Does $G$ have a model over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: No, for instance if the endomorphism ring has ramification over $\Bbb Q_p$, the model can’t be defined over $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Another concrete example other than that furnished by @Lubin comes from an elliptic curve with potentially good reduction.

Comment: Thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list. This is false even if you replace $\mathbb{C}_p$ by a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. When I want to think of concrete examples of $p$-divisible groups that are interesting (e.g. of height larger than $1$) then I often times think of abelian varieties.

In this case we can use the following well-known theorem of Grothendieck (see [1, Exp. IX, Thm. 5.13]):

> *Theorem(Grothendieck):* Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field and $A$ an abelian variety over $K$. Then, $A$ has good reduction if and only if $A[p^\infty]$ has a good reduction.

So, in this light, a positive answer to your question would imply that an abelian variety with potentially good reduction has good reduction. But, of course, this is false:

*Example:* The elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+p$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has additive bad reduction but $E_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[3]{p})}$ has good reduction. So, $E[p^\infty]$ does not admit a model over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but $E[p^\infty]_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[3]{p})}$ admits a model over $\mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt[3]{p}]$.

[1]  A. Grothendieck, *Groupes de monodromie en géometrie algébrique*, LNM **288**, **340**, Springer–Verlag,
New York, 1972-3.